# Are the failure of SCH and "$cf([\mu]^{cf (\mu)},\subset)>\mu^+$ for some singular" equiconsistent?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is it true that the following two statements are equiconsistent?

(1) $2^\mu>\mu^+$ for some strong limit singular cardinal $\mu$

(2) $cf([\mu]^{cf (\mu)},\subset)>\mu^+$  for some singular cardinal $\mu$

Thanks.

Comment: Note that for any two cardinals $\mu \geq\kappa$, $\mu^\kappa = cf([\mu]^\kappa, \subseteq) \cdot 2^\kappa$ so the first statement implies the second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is stated by Yair Hayut, in the comment above, statement $(1)$ implies statement $(2)$. Let's show that statement $(2)$ does not imply statement $(1)$.

Let $u(\kappa, \lambda)=cf(P_\kappa(\lambda), \subseteq),$ so that $cf([\mu]^{cf(\mu)}, \subseteq)=u(cf(\mu)^+, \mu).$

As it is stated in  [Large cardinals and covering numbers](http://journals.impan.pl/cgi-bin/doi?fm205-1-3), one can obtain a model of $u(\omega_1, \omega_\omega)>\omega_{\omega}^+$$+SCH$ by adding $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ many Cohen reals to a model in which $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$ and $GCH$ holds everywhere else.

Of course this does not imply that statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ have different consistency strength.

On the other hand Shelah's Strong Hypothesis (SSH) is equivalent to the statement $u(\kappa, \lambda)\leq \lambda^+$ for all cardinals $\kappa\leq \lambda,$ with $\kappa$ regular. However it is not known whether the failure of SSH is equiconsistent
with that of SCH.

Comment: Could you send me a reference to the statement "SSH iff $u(\kappa,\lambda)\le \lambda^+$ for all $\kappa\le \lambda$, with $\lambda$ regular" (I did not know it)

Comment: @LajosSoukup It is stated in the paper mentioned above. Please see the introduction of the paper.

Comment: Thank you. Concerning the origin of this result I asked Assaf, and he wrote me that this statement  also appeared in Sh400B (Shelah: Cardinal Arithmetics for sceptics)